# New dataframe from grouping together two columns

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, sklearn-pandas

I have a dataset that looks like the following.

```
Region_Name  Date     Average
London       1990Q1   105
London       1990Q1   118
...          ...      ...
London       2018Q1   157
```

I converted the date into quarters and wish to create a new dataframe with the matching quarters and region names grouped together, with the mean average.
What is the best way to accomplish such a task.

I have been looking at the groupby function but keep getting a traceback.
for example:

```
new_df = df.groupby(['Resion_Name','Date']).mean()
```

Comment: Your groupby contains a typo. Try `new_df = df.groupby(['Region_Name', 'Date']).mean()`

Comment: Also, note that the default behaviour of `groupby` is to insert the grouped-by columns into the index of the resulting DataFrame. If you group by multiple columns, you get a `MultiIndex`. To keep the grouped-by columns as normal columns, use `groupby(as_index=False)`, or if the result is `df`, run `df = df.reset_index()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
dict3={'Region_Name': ['London','Newyork','London','Newyork','London','London','Newyork','Newyork','Newyork','Newyork','London'],
'Date' : ['1990Q1','1990Q1','1990Q2','1990Q2','1991Q1','1991Q1','1991Q2','1992Q2','1993Q1','1993Q1','1994Q1'],
'Average': [34,56,45,67,23,89,12,45,67,34,67]}


df3=pd.DataFrame(dict3)
```

**Now My df3 is as follows **

```
    Region_Name Date    Average

0   London  1990Q1  34


1   Newyork 1990Q1  56

2   London  1990Q2  45

3   Newyork 1990Q2  67

4   London  1991Q1  23

5   London  1991Q1  89

6   Newyork 1991Q2  12

7   Newyork 1992Q2  45

8   Newyork 1993Q1  67

9   Newyork 1993Q1  34

10  London  1994Q1  67
```

code looks as follows:

```
new_df = df3.groupby(['Region_Name','Date'])

new1=new_df['Average'].transform('mean')
```

Result of dataframe `new1`:

```
print(new1)


0     34.0

1     56.0

2     45.0

3     67.0

4     56.0

5     56.0

6     12.0

7     45.0

8     50.5

9     50.5

10    67.0
```